# Convert 1 channel image to 3 channel

Tags: opencv

I am trying to convert a 1 channel image (16 bit) to a 3 channel image in OpenCV 2.3.1. I am having trouble using the merge function and get the following error:

```
    Mat temp, tmp2;
    Mat hud;
    tmp2 = cv_ptr->image;
    tmp2.convertTo(temp, CV_16UC1);
    temp = temp.t();
    cv::flip(temp, temp, 1);
    resize(temp, temp, Size(320, 240));
    merge(temp, 3, hud);
```

error: no matching function for call to ‘merge(cv::Mat&, int, cv::Mat&)’

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

If `temp` is the 1 channel matrix that you want to convert to 3 channels, then the following will work:

```
cv::Mat out;
cv::Mat in[] = {temp, temp, temp};
cv::merge(in, 3, out);
```

check the [Documenation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge#cv.Merge) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that does not require replicating the single channel image before creating a 3-channel image from it.  The memory footprint of this solution is 3 times less than the solution that uses merge (by volting above).
See openCV documentation for cv::mixChannels if you want to understand why this works

```
// copy channel 0 from the first image to all channels of the second image
int from_to[] = { 0,0, 0,1, 0,2}; 
Mat threeChannelImage(singleChannelImage.size(), CV_8UC3);
mixChannels(&singleChannelImage, 1, & threeChannelImage, 1, from_to, 3);
```

Comment: This is a clean and short solution, but it has no advantage over the solution proposed by volting, that was also short, clean and had same memory footprint. Using {temp, temp, temp} does not replicate image 3 times, but it replicate only its header.

Comment: You see the line that says: cv::Mat in[] = {temp temp, temp};
My solution above avoids allocation of memory for in[] which is 3 times the size of the original image.  Note that this is in addition to the 3-channel out array that both solutions require.

Comment: The line you mentioned is not allocating memory. It creates 3 matrix headers (few bytes each) that share same image buffer as the image 'temp'.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you aren't quite using `merge` correctly. You need to specify all of the cannels that are to be 'merged'. I think you want a three channel frame, with all the channels identical, in Python I would write this:

```
cv.Merge(temp, temp, temp, None, hud)
```

From the opencv [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#merge):

> cvMerge: Composes a multi-channel array from several single-channel arrays or inserts a single channel into the array.