# OpenCV: How to convert CV_8UC1 mat to CV_8UC3

Tags: opencv

How to convert CV_8UC1 Mat to CV_8UC3 with OpenCV?

```
Mat dst;
Mat src(height, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char*) captureClient->data());
src.convertTo(dst, CV_8UC3);
```

but dst.channels() = 1

Comment: what are you actually trying to ask?

Comment: Do you want the 3-channel image to have the same pixel values in all channels as the 1-channel image?

Answer (score 33):

I've found that the best way to do this is:

```
cvtColor(src, dst, COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
```

The image will look the same as when it was grayscale CV_8UC1 but it will be a 3 channel image of type CV_8UC3.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) on convertTo

> > void Mat::convertTo(Mat& m, int rtype, double alpha=1, double beta=0) const
> >
> > rtype – The desired destination matrix type, or rather, the depth **(since the number of channels will be the same with the source one)**. If rtype is negative, the destination matrix will have the same type as the source.

You want to create a matrix for each of the 3 channels you want to create and then use the merge function.  See the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970660/convert-1-channel-image-to-3-channel/13636230#13636230) question

Answer (score 3):

The convention is, that for the type `CV_8UC3`, the pixels values range from `0` to `255`, and for type `CV_32FC3` from `0.0` to `1.0`. Thus you need to use a scaling factor of `255.0`, instead of `1.0`:

```
Mat::convertTo(newImage, CV_32FC1, 255.0);
```